# Nrwl nx caching not working on docker container in jenkins

Tags: angular, docker, jenkins, caching, nrwl-nx

Nrwl nx caching not working on docker container  in jenkins 
Each time i invoke the build the lint, build and test is running again instead of taking from cache .

**Docker file**

```
FROM kaptest/docker-atomapi-node:10

WORKDIR /app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/
RUN npm install --quiet

# for merging cobertura
RUN wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tgsoverly/ef975d5b430fbce1eb33/raw/a4836655814bf09ac34bd42a6dd99f37aea7265d/merge-xml-coverage.py

# Bundle app source
COPY . /app

# Volume where the distributable site will be dropped
VOLUME /app/dist

CMD bash -c "npm run affected:lint -- --base=remotes/origin/master --head=HEAD --parallel --maxParallel=10 && \
  npm run affected:test -- --base=remotes/origin/master --head=HEAD --parallel --maxParallel=10 && \
  npm run affected:build -- --base=remotes/origin/master --prod --head=HEAD --parallel --maxParallel=10"
```

Answer (score 1):

Nx stores the cache locally in the node_modules folder. This means that you won't have access to the cache files. You can solve this by adding the node_modules folder as a volume, or better yet use Nx Cloud for caching (see https://nx.app/ and https://github.com/nrwl/nx-distributed-cache-example).

Comment: can you ELI5? I've setup nx-cloud and my docker containers are still using their own cache. I must be missing something. I guess I have to use .circleci? No bringing your own Dockerfile? How would I run this locally then?